# How to change the product list template of one category without affacting product list templates for other categories

Tags: magento

I would like to display one sub-category products as list only. The products list in this category is only shown product title, price and weight. But other categories and sub-categories products are still kept the default layout(have images.product title/ brief description).

Is there anyone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put something like this in the `Custom Layout Update` value of the category :

```
<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>your_custom_template.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: @bImage, where should I add the above code to? Is it app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\catalog.xml?

Comment: In the admin, there is a `Custom Layout Update` field in the `Custom Design` tab of the category edit page. You can put there some XML that will be used to update the layout of the given category page.

Comment: @bImage, which folder should put file(your_custom_template.phtml)?

Comment: In fact, you can put it in the folder you want, and also name it as you want, as long as you put the correct path in the layout update. However, for consistency, you may prefer to put it in the `catalog/product/list/` folder of your theme.

Comment: @bImage, the default layout template of product list is on `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml`. Then I made a copy of list.phtml and named it as newlist.phtml. what path should be on code `<template>newlist.phtml</template>`?

Comment: Everything after `/template/`, so `catalog/product/list/newlist.phtml`